# How to track App Engine metrics by endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, monitoring, metrics, google-cloud-monitoring

I'd like to track metrics for my App Engine app segmented by endpoint:

- views/second by page
- requests/second by endpoint
- response times by endpoint

I've found metrics that look like they'd be helpful, like [`http/server/response_count`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#appengine/http/server/response_count) and [`http/server/response_latencies`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#appengine/http/server/response_latencies) but there doesn't seem to be a way to group them by endpoint. How can I do this?

Comment: Add a link to the metrics you said you can't find a way of grouping by endpoint

Comment: Thanks @NoCommandLine, I just added the links you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I could get what I wanted by creating log-based metrics:

[image]

The trick is to add a label based on the path (`protoPayload.resource`):

[image]

Now group by `path` in the metrics explorer:

[image]